# how to use a resource in a storyboard using TargetName

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, resourcedictionary

As below I would like to set the TargetName to movingImage so that the image moves across the screen left to right. Visual Studio throws an error and am not sure how to reference it correctly. I would like to keep the image in a resource dictionary and bring it in programmatically as required.

I have the following resource:

```xml
                <Canvas.Resources>

                <Storyboard x:Key="myStory">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="movingImage"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                     Duration="0:0:5"
                                     From="-157"
                                     To="78"/>
                </Storyboard>

                <Image x:Key="movingImage"
                       Canvas.Left="-157"
                       Source="Resource\myImage.png"/>

                </Canvas.Resources>
```

And have brought the Storyboard and Image as follows in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
myCanvas.Children.Add(myCanvas.FindResource("movingImage") as UIElement);
sb = myCanvas.FindResource("myStory") as Storyboard;
sb.Begin();
```

The error I am getting is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'movingImage' name cannot be found in the
> name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Canvas'.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'movingImage' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Canvas'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these changes :

1. Change Key of Image control to `movingImageKey`, and name to `movingImage`.

   ```
      <Image x:Key="movingImageKey" x:Name="movingImage" 
              Canvas.Left="-157"
              Source="Penguins.jpg"/>
   ```

   Code :

   ```
       NameScope.SetNameScope(myCanvas, new NameScope());

       Image img = (myCanvas.FindResource("movingImageKey") as Image);
       myCanvas.RegisterName(img.Name, img);
       myCanvas.Children.Add(img);

       Storyboard sb = myCanvas.FindResource("myStory") as Storyboard;
       sb.Begin();
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes suggested and it works as intended.

Comment: X:key does not exist in my grid